# String attribute in Android XML resources with RTL language

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, attributes

To display an attribute in an xml string :

```
<string name="version_label">Version: %1$s</string>
```

But in an RTL language like Arabic, how do you do it?

When I copy the "%1$s" in android studio:

```
<string name="version_label">s$الإصدار : %1</string>
```

Is it correct or a bug ?

Comment: Ive made it before, that way and its correct

Comment: res/layout-ldrtl/ (Right to Left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a bug. Android allow special characters in string.xml. for more deep you have check  this link : 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: It seems to work but the inverted display of "%1$s" is really weird and when I open it with gedit, it shows me:  <string name="version_label">الإصدار : %1$s</string>