# Format string in Arabic (Localizable string)

Tags: android, formatting, arabic

I am stuck in translating English to Arabic with below string value. Please support:

This is en\strings.xml file for English and default

```
<string name="pay_now">%1$s will be charged from your card now</string>
```

In ar\strings.xml for Arabic

```
<string name="insurance_description_carla_carla_plus">سيتم خصم٪1$s من بطاقتك الآن</string>
```

[image]

Code for string formatation

```
val strPaynow = getString(R.string.pay_now, 10.5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String attribute in Android XML resources with RTL language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743540/string-attribute-in-android-xml-resources-with-rtl-language)